# Will there any data loss while upgrading kafka client from 0.8.0 to 0.10.0.1?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

we are planning to upgrade Kafka client from 0.8.0 to 0.10.0.1 but since in consumers the offset in 0.8.0 version is stored in zookeeper where as it is stored in broker in version 0.10.0.1, if we start  consumer with the same group and client id as of version 0.8.0 in 0.10.0.1 then will new consumer fetch the messages from where old consumer stopped consuming. If data loss is going to happen can we try migrating the offsets from zookeeper to broker and then start our new consumer

Comment: Take a look at this: https://archive.cloudera.com/kafka/kafka/2/kafka-0.10.0-kafka2.1.0/upgrade.html

Comment: Also check this : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue storing offsets in zookeeper on 0.10. In fact, if you just upgraded the client binaries, you won't see any change in the offset commit behavior. Where you will have to start thinking about migration of data and offsets is when you move to using the new consumer API in your application. This is where you will need to stop your old application instance based on the old API, check the offsets stored in zookeeper, and then start the new consumer API implementation from that offset to about data loss or duplication.